# Angular velocity: $\omega = vr$ or $\omega = v/r$?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, orbital-motion, textbook-erratum

Which one is the formula of angular velocity? Is it $\omega= vr$? If not then why does the source below use $mvr=nh/2\pi$, where $mvr$ is angular momentum and $vr$ is angular velocity? Again $\omega=v/r$ shows radian per second. I saw $\omega= vr$ in one book and $\omega= v/r$ in another!

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: $\omega$ is angular velocity (in $\mathrm{s^{-1}}$), $v$ is speed (in $\mathrm{ms^{-1}}$). $v=\omega R$: just look at the units.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Comment: $\vec \omega=\frac{\vec r \times\vec v}{|\vec r|^2}$

Comment: What does dimensional analysis tell you?

Comment: Dimension analysis tell me it should be w=v/r! But tge formular mvr= n*h/2*pi is extensive ly used! Can it be wrong?!!

Comment: It is used for angular momentum which is not $m\omega$...

Comment: Hi Nayeem Nmn. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: @Qmchanic sorry about that! New here!

Comment: Your first image is wrong - the identification of $vr$ as an angular velocity is plain wrong. Find a better textbook. (On the other hand, the formula $mvr=nh/2\pi$ isn't wrong - you just need to set the angular momentum $L=mvr$ as equal to $m\omega r^2$.)

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty yes! Got it!

Comment: Textbook misprint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular momentum has dimensions of momentum times distance. The expression $mvr$ does NOT equate with $m\omega$; angular momentum would be $I\omega$ where $I$ is the moment of inertia.

Answer (score 1):

Angular velocity:

$$\omega=v/r$$

Angular momentum:

$$L=pr=mvr$$

I believe you are confused because you mixed the expressions for (linear) momentum and angular momentum:

- *Momentum* equals *velocity* times *mass*, so $p=mv$.
- ***Angular*** momentum equals ***angular*** velocity times ***"angular"*** mass. And this "angular" mass is what we call moment of inertia I. So $L=I\omega$.

I seems that you tried to read $L=m\omega$ from the text in the book, which does not work.

Comment: But  in the first picture vr= velocity is shown!again Momentum = mass *velocity! Shouldn't angular velocity * mass be angular momentum?

Comment: @NayeemNmn Momentum equals *velocity* times  *mass*. **Angular** momentum equals **angular** velocity times "**angular**" mass. And this "angular" mass is what we call *moment of inertia* $I$.

Comment: @NayeemNmn Look at the first picture again more closely: It doesn't say that $vr=\omega$; it says that angular momentum is equal to $mvr$.